# Programmatic way to rewrite a query with the view definitions as sub query?

Tags: sql-server

Wondering if anyone has found or knows of a way to programmatically re-write a query to use the view definition as a subquery?

For example, let's say I have a view:

```sql
CREATE VIEW View1
AS
select * from table1
go
```

I want to be able to take the query:

```sql
select * from View1
```

And have it automatically rewritten as

```sql
select *
from (
  select * from table1
) as View1
```

This is a simple example, but I'd like to be able to do this for more complex queries, for example, if a view references another view, or there are multiple views joined together.  Rather than manually looking at the definitions of all the views and rewriting it manually, I was hoping to come up with a way to do this programatically some how.  I could probably figure something out on my own, but I just wanted to ask first in case someone knows of something that already does this so I don't have to recreate the wheel.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: For a pet project I'm working on.  Plus, sometimes I think it's easier to figure out what's going on in an execution plan when I am able to see the actual table queries, rather than the query text just being "select * from view"

Comment: If it is just for a few queries, I would download a copy of RedGate SQL Prompt. Then it is easy to see and grab the underlying code.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of or seen anything of this ilk.

You're most likely better served rethinking how you utilize views and refactoring them in a way that isn't an impediment to development, instead of building a tool to do this.

Several layers of nested views are (to me) an anti-pattern and make it [harder for developers and SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5487/is-nested-view-a-good-database-design) alike. They're also very likely to [hide bad code and obscure issues](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2020/05/your-views-arent-the-problem-your-code-is/).

Also see:

- [The Seven Sins Against TSQL](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven): Indulging in Nested Views